# I am trying to build an Android app by kivy but buildozer init keeping fail

Tags: python, kivy

Hello I try to do buildozer init but i got this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vanthao/.local/bin/buildozer", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vanthao/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/vanthao/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1010, in run_command
    getattr(self, cmd)(*args)
  File "/home/vanthao/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1049, in cmd_init
    copyfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'default.spec'), 'buildozer.spec')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'buildozer.spec'
```

Could anyone explain what problem I am facing and how to resolve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can meen, your variable src isn't correct.
If

```
 src = "C:\User\name\folder_exemple"
```

Add a "r" before the path value:

```
src = r"C:\User\name\folder_exemple"
```